# Error When enter data incorrect in FilterTree

Tags: java, tree, swt, jface, rcp

I have create a FilterTree, when i enter correct data to filter and search, it displays the correct results. But when I enter incorrect data (For example: "asdjahsdkjhsaldkj"). It will be error, And I dont know why ?

This is my src :

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {

    filterTree = new FilteredTree(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
            | SWT.V_SCROLL, new PatternFilter(), true);

    treeviewer = filterTree.getViewer();
    treeviewer.setContentProvider(new TreeViewContentProvider());
    treeviewer.setLabelProvider(new TreeViewLabelProvider());
    treeviewer.setInput(treeData.getAllType());
    treeviewer.addDoubleClickListener(this);
    getSite().setSelectionProvider(treeviewer);
}
```

And This is Error:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.StackOverflowError)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3645)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3568)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runPendingMessages(Display.java:1196)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.safeReadAndDispatch(Display.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:1168)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2733)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2694)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$5(Workbench.java:2530)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:701)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:157)
    at peyton.training.rap.demoSecond.Application.start(Application.java:18)
    at org.eclipse.rap.ui.internal.application.EntryPointApplicationWrapper.createUI(EntryPointApplicationWrapper.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle.createUI(RWTLifeCycle.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle$UIThreadController.run(RWTLifeCycle.java:284)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.UIThread.run(UIThread.java:105)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Vector.equals(Vector.java:981)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.equals(StructuredViewer.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doFindInputItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:872)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.findItems(StructuredViewer.java:793)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.findItem(StructuredViewer.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalGetWidgetToSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1694)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1590)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1590)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1590)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1590)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1590)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1590)
```

Comment: At a guess your tree content provider `getParent()` method is not working correctly.

Comment: Yes, That's right. I have set return default at method getparent is "new Object()" And it's wrong, I had set " return null " -> It's correct.
Thank you so much !